# How to create a custom php linter for visual studio code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, linter

I would like implement a linter into my php project (I'm using visual studio code).

I would like to set many options, example:

```
// Bad
if ($foo) {
 return $bar;
}
// Good
if ($foo)
 return $bar;
```

How can I do this ? It must be simple to do

Comment: The second one is definetely bad. There are some linters that implements a lot of rules. You can think about use some.

Comment: It's an example. It's obvious I'll not do this. I want a linter but I want to edit some rules.

Comment: `It must be simple to do` .. Why.  You can look into  PSR1 and PSR2 and this [Linter](https://cs.sensiolabs.org/).  I made a background process that whenever a file is changed it gets linted ... :)  I cant share it though, as it's "company" property.